# Basic Topology: Need example

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I need help finding an example of an infinitely uncountable set that contains only isolated points.  I so far have been completely unsuccessful and have only found uncountable set with no isolated points.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What about $\,\Bbb R\,$ with the discrete topology...?

Comment: Let $U$ be the subset of all isolated ordinals of space $\omega_1+1$, then U is uncountable.

Answer (score 6):

Take the discrete metric space $(X,d)$ where $X$ is uncountable

Answer (score 5):

There is no example as a subset of $\mathbb R^d$ (with the standard topology), or in any other separable metric space.

Each of your uncountably many points would, by definition, be surrounded by a ball that contains no other points in the set. *A priori* these balls may intersect, but you can avoid that by halving the radius of each of them. Then $\mathbb R^d$ would contain uncountably many *disjoint* balls. But that is impossible because each of the balls contains a point with rational coordinates, and there are only countably many of those to go around!

On the other hand, if you don't need your set to live in $\mathbb R^d$, then Michael Touitou's suggestion just to take a discrete metric will do the trick.